# does PHP simple html dom parser conflict with wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

does PHP simple html dom parser conflict with wordpress ?
cause whenever I try to include it with this code in my header
everything goes blank  :@

Thanks for any help in advance !!

```
<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/php/simple_html_dom.php'); ?>
```

Comment: `is_file(TEMPLATEPATH.'/php/simple_html_dom.php')`?... WP must be silencing errors, try turning error reporting on before your include: `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: thanks tried that error doesn't say anything ... I echo is_file it prints 1 , does that mean one file ?

Comment: Use `var_dump(is_file($file))` instead of echo. But no, the `1` means `TRUE` (when you echo TRUE that's what happens), so the file seems to be found.

Comment: thanks not sure why I can't include in my header.php, tried somewhere else too : ((

Comment: You just need to access the PHP error message and all will be clear.

Comment: I put this in 
<?php var_dump(error_reporting(E_ALL)); include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/php/simple_html_dom.php'); ?>

and it returns this int(4983)

Comment: I guess you have to turn `WP_DEBUG` on (I'm not a WP user). Try this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug `4983` is just the value that `E_ALL` contains, ignore that - it's not what you want to var_dump(), see manual on what error reporting does: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: thanks man I will have a read !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to use a PHP include in the  of the HTML document.

But it works when I use the include in functions.php (within my theme directory). The exact code was:

```
require_once('library/simple_html_dom.php');
```

Where I placed the Simple HTML DOM Parser in a subdirectory called library.