# Class 'simple_html_dom' not found on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to include simple html dom parser into the search.php on Wordpress,
I added the file simple_html_dom.php in the theme folder and include it in functions.php like this

```
require_once(TEMPLATEPATH.'/simple_html_dom.php');
```

this instruction return 1 when using a var_dump
When execution the search I got this error

> Class 'simple_html_dom' not found

Edit: I didn't announce that I copied str_get_html function on functions.php from simple_html_dom.php
When I removed the function and use str_get_html on function.php
the error will be

> Call to undefined function str_get_html()

The project is hosted on https://c9.io and use Git.
I will be grateful if someone help me to fix this error.

Comment: Have you tried [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16561235/3282633) ?

Comment: I'm beginner on Wordpress require_once('library/simple_html_dom.php');
I add folder in theme folder or root folder?

Answer (score 1):

You should not copy any function from the 'simple_html_dom.php' file, because the risk is for you to have 2 declarations of the same method name (which will end badly), and the methods  within the simple_html_dom.php file interact with classes/ other methods also in the file, so, at some point, you will need to copy one of them too.
So rather than copying a lot of code, use the include/require statments of PHP (their are here for that after all).

Your first approach is correct:
1 - include the class file
2 - use the methods/classes in it

So to include a file in your theme's 'functions.php' file,
you can* :
a - use a constant like you did (TEMPLATEPATH) :

```
require_once TEMPLATEPATH . '/simple_html_dom.php';
```

b - use get_template_directory() which give you the absolute path to the them folder currently used :

```
require_once get_template_directory() . '/simple_html_dom.php';
```

- assuming 'simple_html_dom.php' is on root of your theme folder.

What is the value of your constant TEMPLATEPATH?
Maybe the problem is just here.

Comment: Ifixed the problem, i used an old version of the API